# Install python module from diferrent directory

Tags: python, module, python-2.x

I have found a custom http requests python module that greatly simplifies my task.

To be specific this one : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

So i downloaded the package from a site. Extracted the archive and attempted to install the module.

When i use the following command from the directory where the module is:

```
python setup.py install
```

it works flawlessly and the module is installed.

But i am wondering how can i do it from other directory ? When i try this:

```
python /home/some_user/setup.py install
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/some_user/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
    with open('requests/__init__.py', 'r') as fd:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/codecs.py", line 881, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requests/__init__.py'
```

I am asking because i will be needing to install it remotely to other machines.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please read official Python guide for installing packages. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments - I recommend using tools `pip`  and `virtualenv` to make isolated Python installations in different folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you not need to manage this package using `pip` (as you not installed package from pip repository), you could just copy content of `kennethreitz-requests-a693753/requests` folder to `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/requests/`, where x.x is your python version, like 3.4

By that way, ***package wouldn't be managed by any setup tool*** - you need to manage package manually, but you can freely import `requests` module and use it.

P.S. As variant - create rpm/deb package and distribute across systems well fast

Answer (score 0):

A good idea, as said @Mikko Ohtamaa, use `pip` and `virtualenv`. Also you can add path in python where is located you module. There two ways: [sys.path and PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd line of the traceback

```
with open('requests/__init__.py', 'r') as fd:
```

makes it clear that `setup.py` uses a relative path to locate the file `requests/__init__.py`. If you know the full path, where the remote machines will find the module, you can adjust `setup.py` to use this absolute path, instead of the relative one.
I suggest reviewing all of `setup.py`, since it might try to locate more than just `__init__.py`.